# Should I Open/Close SpriteBatch with different settings?

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm still new in game developpement, and I'm trying to complete my 1st game. Its a simple 2d game, but i'm trying to add lots of differents techniques in it.

It's all good when you take a single tutorial (I followed some tutorials for the screen managers, for diffuse lightning, for camera, HUD, particles, spritesheet animations, etc. ) 
It's all quite simple to get it to works and run in a simple game.cs file.

the problem I have is when its time to all mix it toghether. I cant find any good pointers on how I should handle the spritebatch orderings. Should I use different spritebatch, or reuse the same over and over ? I was told I need to utilise as little spritebatch as possible ...

** I KNOW i could test it and start to wonder about it only if I have a problem ... but instead I'd prefer to learn to do it right the 1st time I try it. If I get into a bigger project and this way of doing it only works on easy small 2d game ... its not much better than saying I've never done anything.

More specificly, I'm wondering if I keep my main Draw set up like this :

```
 graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);            

 spriteBat.Begin(paramteres set up for my camera); 
   for each screen in screenmanager {
     screen.draw(spritebatch);
   }
 spriteBat.End(); 


  spriteBat.Begin(paramteres set up for my HUD); 
     //draw hud stuff
  spriteBat.End();
```

....

and in my screens draw method ... i'll end up with :

```
void Draw(spritebat Spritebatch)
{
     //draw screen "normal" item affected by camera 
  spriteBat.End(); 

  spriteBat.Begin(paramteres set up for particle); 
    for each particlelist in particlemanager {
      for each particle in particleList
        particle.draw(spritebatch);
      }
    }
   spriteBat.End(); 


 spriteBat.Begin(paramteres set up for my light FX); 
    //draw diffuse light and shadows stuff
 spriteBat.End();

 spriteBat.Begin(paramteres set up for my camera); 
}
```

is this correct ?

Comment: should I move this into a code review oriented site ? its bordeline on "best practice" questions that will often ended up closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is how spritebatch is meant to be used. It takes a view matrix in the begin parameter and uses that throughout the begin/end pair. You could argue that spritebatch would be more flexible with matrices if you could pass a view matrix in for each .draw call, but evidently the XNA team decided against this for one reason or another. To answer your question, having two seperate begin/ends won't make THAT much difference overall. Tutorials often make a note of using as little begin/end as possible to make the reader knows that it should not be called once for every draw call or nested somewhere in a class' .draw method.

The biggest problem I've found this leading to is when you have a .draw method in another class that relies on a spritebatch being begun. If that is the case, this method can only draw with one view matrix. This can be a bit of a problem, but shouldn't be too hard to get around.

Spritebatch .begin changes a lot of the state with the GPU. This is pretty expensive, but two calls per frame is very reasonable and shouldn't be a problem. If your 2D application is lagging on a decent modern computer, you should look for issues elsewhere.

Comment: Well, technically it could be alot more than 2, since each screens will open and close the spritebatch. I could have up to 3 or 4 screens at the same time

Comment: Screens? You mean different viewports?

Comment: screens are just an object that holds what you see on the screen .. like "windows". I have a mini-map "screen", my hud "screen", world map "screen", battle-map "screen", combat "screen", inventory "screen", etc ...

Comment: They shouldn't be drawn if they're not visible. They aren't ALL visible at the same time, right?

Comment: they could be. You can have a battle map, inventory, hud, et maybe an alert/acheivement message on at the same time. ex : Achievement is a small, a 200x200 "windows".

Comment: I have a screen manager, and it draws only screen that are active ( theres a "hidden" state if I want to update one and not draw it ). Its based on the "adventure in xna" tutorial, which use an upgrade version of the msdn screen management tutorial

Comment: it works good on its own, but its when I add lightning and particles and camera and hsls with different render that is starts to get messy, and I end up having a bunch of begin/end spritebatch ... I'm even wondering if I should not use 1 spritebatch for camera, and create 1 special spritebatch for particule, and just use them at the same time ... not sure its good practice though.

Comment: Well, every different shader you use will have to have it's own begin and end. That's just the way it is, begin sets up a rendering state and the shader is a big part of that state. I wouldn't worry about it if I was you. It's the way XNA is designed, so you really have to trust that Microsoft are doing it right( they most probably are ). There really only needs to be one begin/end per coordinate space. For instance, everything in your HUD is in screen space, and your map for instance might be in world space, so that'll need it's own begin/end. If you don't like it this way, then manually

Comment: transform each one of your vectors instead of using the begin overload. This will work just as well.

Comment: alright, thanks alot. I wasnt sure if I was setting something wrong or if there was a concept I was missing.